# Postcode lookup: nonetype object not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, gps, nonetype

I've got what I think is a super basic problem, but it's got me stumped...

I've got a bunch of longitude/lattitude coordinates in a dataframe and want to look up what UK postcode they are in, and return the answer in a new column in the dataframe.

I've found an API to do the look up and written a function. But when I try and execute this function in my new column, I get a 'Nonetype Object not subscriptable' error

Code is as follows:

```
def get_postcode (lon,lat):
    r = requests.get(f"http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes?lon={lon}&lat={lat}")
    req = json.loads(r.content)
    data = req.get("result")[0]
    postcode = data["postcode"]
    return postcode


df['Postcode'] = df.apply(lambda row: (get_postcode(row.Longitude,row.Lattitude)),axis=1)
```

Any pointers much appreciated. I'm really new to this and trying to learn as I go - I'm sure there are far more elegant ways of solving this problem

Thank you

Comment: Look at the result with `print(req)`

Comment: What I call that API with my latitude and longitude I get `{"status":200,"result":null}`

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your error. It's a consequence of an empty result, as mentioned in the comments. It seems like an empty result means "outside of UK" or at least "don't know the postcode".

For random point in London from Google Maps:

```
get_postcode(51.521430, -0.078525)
# > TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

However, surprisingly it helped to swap lat and lon:

```
get_postcode(-0.078525, 51.521430)
# > 'E1 6DB'
```

Which is correct.

In my experience, lat and lon are commonly mixed up.